# Добавить значения в List<String>

Tags: java, android

```
List<String> allPhoto = new ArrayList<>();
```

`String` - так понимаю в данном контексте это класс, который наследует Объект.

Но если мне нужно добавить туда параметры, или не знаю как правильней сказать, переменные чтоли, то как я могу это сделать?

Нашёл несколько решений:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add(textview.getText().toString());
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
```

Но мне такое не совсем подходит. Можно внести немного ясности в этот загадочный класс?

Например мне нужно добавить фотографии, которые будут добавляться из галлереи в список.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Что вы хотите добавить в List? Приведите пример что ли

Comment: Конечно, только сначала Вам следует внести немного ясности в то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: @Igor обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> String - так понимаю в данном контексте это класс, который наследует Объект.

Коллега, чтобы понимать правильно, выполните простой алгоритм:

1. Напишите ваш код в IDE.
2. Зажмите `ctrl` и щелкните мышкой на непонятном слове.

В вашем случае `String` - эта та самая строка. То есть ваш

```
 List<String> allPhoto = new ArrayList<>();
```

Будет содержать строки, а не фотографии. 
Это просто коллекция, если угодно - динамический массив, то есть он меняет длину, при внесении новых элементов. Как вам сказал автор выше, в угловых в скобках показывается тип объекта, который будет элементом массива.

Как я понял, у вас есть некий класс фото, который имеет некоторый поля. К примеру, длина и ширина. Пусть он реализован как-то так (совсем упрощенно):

```
 public class Photo {
 int width; //ширина
 int height; //высота

 public int getWidth() { //геттер длины
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() { //геттер высоты
    return height;
}

public Photo(int width, int height) { //конструктор
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
}
```

Тогда ваш список примет вид:

```
 List<Photo> allPhoto = new ArrayList<>();
```

Пусть вам вздумалось добавить объект класса фото. Делайте это так:

```
     allPhoto.add(0, new Photo(800, 600)); //в нулевой элемент добавить фото 800*600
     allPhoto.add(1, new Photo(640, 480)); //в первый элемент добавить фото 640*480
     allPhoto.add(2, new Photo(1280, 800)); //во второй элемент добавить фото 1280*800
```

Если у вас есть, как вы говорите "галлерея" то на месте `new Photo` у должна  быть команда типа `addFromGallery` которая возвращает объект класса `Photo`.

Предположим, вам начальство сказало:

> есть коллекция allPhoto. Добудь мне ширину и высоту второй
>   фотографии.

Вы сделаете это так:

```
   Photo ph2 = allPhoto.get(2); //получили второй объект из коллекции;
   int Widthph1 = ph1.getWidth(); //получил ширину из второго фото
   int Heightph1 = ph1.getHeight(); //получил высоту из второго фото
```

Comment: Всё бы конец супер)
но я в силу своей неопытности неправильно местами формулирую задачу.
Мне нужно было получить url - а это как понимаю всё таки строковый ресурс.
И тогда мне стоит прописать примерно следующее?
1. List<String> url = new ArrayList<>();  - плюс я так понял такой способ плохо влияет на memory, и как альтернатива слышал используют temp?
2. url.add(только вот не знаю как обратиться к линку)

Comment: url - действительно строковый. Ну суть не меняется. url - это у вас будет по сути массив ссылок, и имхо он мало на что влияет. 
Пробуйте как-то так 
`url.add(0, "D:\Gallery\MyChildGayPorno\combo1.jpg*");//добавить строку `

Comment: а как обратиться именно к url? когда мы прописываем url.add(???);
Так понимаю нужно обращаться к гетеру в модели моей, так как ссылки вводит пользователь, которые всегда разные.

Comment: после add - первое поле - это номер элемента, куда добавлять. (Вы можете записать ваш объект нулевым, первым ... сто пятьдесят первым и так далее). Второе поле после запятой - это сам объект. В случае url - объектом будет строка.

Answer (score 3):

Когда вы создаёте новый объект для массива, то в угловых скобках сразу указываете, какой тип собираетесь использовать.

Comment: Хорошо, но обычно в угловых скобках помещают название модели, в которую можно потом пихать переменные с гетерами и сеттерами, в чем прикол самого String?

Comment: @Inkognito, где "обычно" такое делают? В джаве? List - это объект контейнер в котором хранятся другие объекты. В угловых скобках вы указываете тип этих хранимых внутри объектов. Всё предельно просто.

Comment: Такое обычно не делают и воще String гдеб ты не видел он тип переменных.это зарезервированное слово и его нельзя нигде использовать кроме типов

Comment: @iksuy List<GroupInfo> groups = new ArrayList<>(); вот на моём же примере, GroupInfo  - модель

Comment: @elik вопрос ЗАЧЕМ использовать <String> ? плюсы, минусы? я не понимаю, извините.

Comment: ааа потомучто если не обьяиш String то ты не сможешь добаить цифры )

Comment: ты даешь знать какие значения будешь использоать)

Comment: @Inkognito, у вас в списке используются элементы конкретного типа. Где-то это `GroupInfo`, где-то `String`. Зачем вам `String` это вы должны знать.

Comment: @elik но сами значения я так понимаю не указываю?

Comment: Друг мой String означает что будет текст а int цифры

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам требуется в списке хранить не просто перечень String, а String в комплекте с некоторыми дополнительными параметрами. 
Этого можно добиться создав структуру данных удовлетворяющую вашим потребностям и уже её помещать в список. Например:

```
class PhotoWithParams {
   String photo;
   String paramA;
   String paramB;
   public PhotoWithParams(String photo, String paramA, String paramB) {
      this.photo = photo;
      this.paramA = paramA;
      this.paramB = paramB;
   }
   // далее геттеры для параметров...
   // public String getPhoto()... и т.д.
}
```

Дальше ваш код:

```
ArrayList<PhotoWithParams> list = new ArrayList<PhotoWithParams>();
list.add(new PhotoWithParams(textview.getText().toString(), "B", "C"));
```